# Can I apply for Schengen without hotel reservation and a local address, as I will be visiting Munich during layover?

Tags: usa, schengen, indian-citizens, layovers

I am an Indian citizen, holding a valid visa for USA. I will be traveling to the United States via Munich, Germany. I have 10 hours of layover at Munich. I would like to visit Munich during the layover. I have two questions.

1. Do I need to apply for a Schengen Visa before my travel?
2. I understood that, Schengen Visa needs proof for hotel reservation and a local address. I do not need a hotel accomodation and a local address, as I will be traveling to the USA. Can I get a Schengen without hotel reservation and a local address?

Appreciate if anyone can guide.

~SAM

Comment: To visit Munich, you need a Schengen visa. If you stay in the airport without passing passport control, you do not need a Schengen visa. For a daytrip, you don't need a hotel booking or address, of course.  It's just that fewpeople make day trips from India to the Schengen area.

Comment: It is not a duplicated entry. There is a question whether I can apply for Schengen without hotel accommodation and an address as I will be visiting Munich during layoer

Comment: Yes, you can do that